# Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type java.util.Set

Tags: java, set, hashset

So I already looked on many questions concerning unchecked calls.

I have this Set:

```
Set<UUID> uuids = new HashSet<>();
```

My getter method is generated by lombok, but I already tried without. (hard-coded getter)

For example:

```
getUuids().add(UUID.randomUUID());
```

Always results in a warning (in IntelliJ)

```
Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type java.util.Set
```

I don't know if that is an error with IntelliJ or if I am missing something.

Comment: How is getter declared?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele public Set<UUID> getUuids() { return this.uuids }

Comment: It seems likely that the return value of getUuids() is `Set` and not `Set<UUID>`.  If so, this is the cause of the warning message.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code is fully using generics and there are no raw types in the code you've shown. There may be some code generation understood by the IDE that's erasing type parameters...

Comment: Having same exact behaviour on IntelliJ but instead of adding into the the object returned by the getter I'm acting on the member variable itself. I actually have a Set<T> and it raises the same Warning if I get a T from an iterator over Set and call functions on it.

Bonus point: It doesn't complain with .remove(T)